Help identify horror/paranormal movie with a woman affected
I've seen a movie over 2 decades ago that i've searched ever since and I can't find it. It's driving me insane. 
I rent it in cassette form so it's most likely an 80's movie.
Here's what i remember:

Family moves into a new house
At first only the woman (i think wife) is affected 
It starts slowly, with mostly a shadow following her around. I remember a scene where she was ironing and you could see a small shadow moving around, lurking.
I THINK the mother in law was the first she told
The events rise in intensity and no one believes her
She gets harrased at night and even with the husband sleeping next to her.
He only believes when one night he wakes up and sees her being "touched" and "groped" by an invisible force.
They eventually leave the house (after that I  believe they perform exorcism)
In the end of the movie it states its based on real events and that the shadow followed her and she was abused for another 5 years or so until it suddenly stopped.

The closest I found was "the entity" from 1981 but that is not the one.
Please someone tell me they saw this too? 
Thank you for any tips and suggestions 

Sounds exactly like The Entity. How does it differ? That might help jog something free.

Can you name any of the actors?

I saw The Entity last night just to confirm and it's not it. I remember specifically a scene where the woman was ironing and a black shadow was moving on the wall behind her. And unlike The Entity, the activity started slow, progressing with time until she was supposedly raped but its not as obvious as in The Entity. I r cognize the similarities but im sure its not the same. And no, i dont remember the actors unfortunately.... it was like 22 years ago i first saw it. Also, i believe there was a mother in law figure or something in it. Not sure about children, maybe one small one.

There is a good chance this is the movie The Haunted (1991) with Sally Kirkland.
At the start a family movie into a new house and Janet (Sally Kirkland) starts to feel as if there is something amiss. There is a part where whilst ironing Janet is visited by a kind of black mist as seen here.
Strange paranormal events escalate and Janet is visited at night while her husband sleeps next to her, he incidentally is sexually abused by the entity later in the movie. 
The family eventually pack up and move, however whatever thing that resided in the other place tags along to the new home.
At the end of the film we find out a Church sanctioned exorcism was the only way to rid the family of the strange being.
I had some pics and things to flesh this out but Im having trouble uploading ATM.
Here are some links.


  The Movie
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102007/  IMDB page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Haunted_(1991_film)  Wiki page.
And an article about this film.
https://veggiemacabre.com/2013/01/18/sally-kirkland-scared-and-smoking/

This sounds very much like what i saw, i will check it out, thank you so much!!!

Thank you!!!!! This is the movie!!!!!! No wonder it was hard to find! I couldn't remember most of the details like the husband being raped and the Warren's being the experts. I didn't even remember the father in law or the kids lol it's a movie made for TV with a low budget (the effects are laughable these days) based on a book by the warrens. I can't thank you enough!!!!!!! My BFF will be so happy we finally found it after 20 years :)

No problem, you could close the out if you like so it wont appear as unanswered.

Havi no clue how to do that but ill try
